# Instagram Basic Display, exchange token error on live

Tags: instagram-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

instagram_graph_user_profile and instagram_graph_user_media are approved but the check mark under Products -> Instagram is not green. Business is verified.
Instagram test users work fine!

We don't have instagram_basic permissions, but as we understand it we won't need it since we don't want do access the facebook graph api (instagram-media or instagram-comment), only the instagram basic display api.

We can get a short-lived access token but the get request to https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token results in {'error': {'message': 'Unsupported get request.', 'code': 100, 'type': u'IGApiException', 'fbtrace_id': u'AJB2dj8osRQbYgG6kNtlmYt'}}

What's going on?